# I disabled my camera years ago and forgot how i did it and now want to re-enable it

Tags: drivers, webcam, kernel-module

I now run Xubuntu version 18.04 last upgraded yesterday.  I disabled the camera on my Kudo Pro laptop a few years ago when i was running either Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04.  I did it by some change in a file.  I believe that file was somewhere in `/etc`.

I remember that I searched Google for a way to do this and the only results i ever got involved blacklisting the camera driver.  Since I was wanting to prevent someone (who might have gotten a program to run that can get enough privileges) from *un*blacklisting it and loading it, I did not want to use that method.  Eventually I found another method that would be "permanent" enough to require rebooting the kernel in order to reload the driver.  That would be good enough as someone could not enable the camera without me noticing that something happened.  The method I found was obviously good enough to keep the camera disabled all these years.

I did not want to cover the camera with tape and I did not want to open up the laptop and disconnect the wires.

That was a few years ago and today I want to re-enable the camera so I can Skype with my family who are staying at their various homes.  Being up in my years, now, my biological memory is not so good, anymore and I forgot how I did that, so I don't know how to *un*do it.  I need to remember to take better notes and keep them where I can easily find them.

My question is:  How might I have disabled the camera in a better (that cannot be undone without rebooting) way than blacklisting that module in the `/etc/modprobe.d/*` files can do?  Maybe there is a blacklist feature inside the kernel that does not allow delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is perhaps specific to either this manufacturer (System 76) or the model (Kudu Pro).  The solution is to press key combination Fn+F10 to toggle enabling/disabling the camera.  When disabled, it does not appear on the USB bus, so this probably disconnects it, logically.  The state (on or off) is preserved across reboots and power cycles.